# The api is returning the date that matches and also dates that does not matches the specified date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'am developing an api in nodejs.
I have the document in follwing stucture:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ecd26504df3372a38afffd9"),
    "balance" : 104000,
    "bankID" : "Bank-1",
    "userEmail" : "kumarshreyas073@gmail.com",
    "bankName" : "Corporation Bank",
    "accountNumber" : "03214569874563",
    "ifsCode" : "CORP0001236",
    "branch" : "Udupi",
    "address" : "Udupi",
    "city" : "Udupi",
    "state" : "Karnataka",
    "openingBalance" : 100000,
    "transactions" : [ 
        {
            "credit" : 2000,
            "debit" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ecd26614df3372a38afffea"),
            "transactionID" : "CashTransaction-5ecd26614df3372a38afffe8",
            "date" : "30-05-2026",
            "particulars" : "By Cash-1",
            "voucherType" : "Cash"
        }, 
        {
            "credit" : 0,
            "debit" : 2000,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ecd272d4df3372a38b00012"),
            "transactionID" : "Receipt-5ecd272d4df3372a38b00009",
            "date" : "29-07-2020",
            "particulars" : "To Suresh kumar",
            "voucherType" : "Receipt"
        }, 
        {
            "credit" : 0,
            "debit" : 2000,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ecd272d4df3372a38b00014"),
            "transactionID" : "Receipt-5ecd272d4df3372a38b00003",
            "date" : "30-05-2024",
            "particulars" : "To Karthik",
            "voucherType" : "Receipt"
        }
    ],
    "idCounter" : 1,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I need to extract only those transactions between from date = "20/07/2020" and to date = "31/07/2020".

The code I written is as follows:

```
exports.trail_balance = async (req, res, next) => {
  var trailBalance = {
    userEmail: req.body.userEmail,
    fromDate: req.body.fromDate,
    toDate: req.body.toDate,
  };

var bankAccount = await Bank.aggregate([
    { $match: { userEmail: req.body.userEmail } },
    {
      $addFields: {
        transactions: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$transactions",
            as: "transactions",
            cond: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $gte: ["$$transactions.date", trailBalance.fromDate],
                },

                {
                  $lte: ["$$transactions.date", trailBalance.toDate],
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ]);

res.status(200).json({
    result: 1,
    bankAccount: bankAccount.length > 0 ? bankAccount : [], 
  });
};
```

Actual result I expect is:

```
{
    "result": 1,
    "bankAccount": [
        {
            "_id": "5ecd26504df3372a38afffd9",
            "balance": 104000,
            "bankID": "Bank-1",
            "userEmail": "kumarshreyas073@gmail.com",
            "bankName": "Corporation Bank",
            "accountNumber": "03214569874563",
            "ifsCode": "CORP0001236",
            "branch": "Udupi",
            "address": "Udupi",
            "city": "Udupi",
            "state": "Karnataka",
            "openingBalance": 100000,
            "transactions": [
                {
                   "credit" : 0,
                   "debit" : 2000,
                   "_id" : ObjectId("5ecd272d4df3372a38b00012"),
                   "transactionID" : "Receipt-5ecd272d4df3372a38b00009",
                   "date" : "29-07-2020",
                   "particulars" : "To Suresh kumar",
                   "voucherType" : "Receipt"
               }
            ],
            "idCounter": 1,
            "__v": 0
      }
```

But, I'am getting all transactions.
I even tried passing date in, from date = "20-07-2020" and to date = "31-07-2020". This too returns all transaction.

All the date stored in DB are of type String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your date format. As you have started your date with `day` in your saved data in database and type of date is `string`, so in comparison to your query, it always start with day and it's incorrect. because in date comparison, at first years must be compared, then months and lastly, day. But you are doing it in wrong way.

In this scenario, mongodb is doing write! because in your `from date`, `2` is less or equal to `2` and `3` and in your `to date`, `3` is greater or equal to `2` and `3`. So its doing well.

I changed your saved data date format to `yyyy-mm-dd` and your query was correct.

If changing data is not possible for you, you can also change data in a pipeline stage of your `aggregate` query. Use the link below:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. The problem is with your data. It has invalid date format.

[mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/akBW4PEzaXl)

I changed to proper date format for one of the transactions as below

```
"date": ISODate("2026-05-30"),
```

[mongo date format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/)

So if you have proper format, then the query will work.

> `new Date("<YYYY-mm-dd>")` returns the ISODate with the specified date.

> `new Date("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss>")` specifies the datetime in the client’s local timezone and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime in UTC.

> `new Date("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ>")` specifies the datetime in UTC and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime in UTC.

> `new Date(<integer>)` specifies the datetime as milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970), and returns the resulting ISODate instance.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the problem. But in case if date is stored in string format in DB too and if we compare request date in string  format does it work?

Comment: If you keep strings, It will be based on string comparison. You can explore `$dateFromString` for this. [reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting few fixes,

- convert your string date to ISO date using `new Date("2020-07-31")`,

```
var trailBalance = {
    userEmail: req.body.userEmail,
    fromDate: new Date(req.body.fromDate),
    toDate: new Date(req.body.toDate),
};
```

- convert collection's field `transactions.date` string to ISO date using [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)
- format: `%d-%m-%Y` should match exact format of date in `transactions.date`

```
{
    $dateFromString: {
        dateString: "$$transactions.date",
        format: "%d-%m-%Y"
    }
}
```

Look at the Working Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/-KWgRCSwD8h

- Your final query,

```
var bankAccount = await Bank.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      userEmail: trailBalance.userEmail
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      transactions: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$transactions",
          as: "transactions",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gte: [
                  {
                    $dateFromString: {
                      dateString: "$$transactions.date",
                      format: "%d-%m-%Y"
                    }
                  },
                  trailBalance.fromDate
                ]
              },
              {
                $lte: [
                  {
                    $dateFromString: {
                      dateString: "$$transactions.date",
                      format: "%d-%m-%Y"
                    }
                  },
                  trailBalance.toDate
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```